# universe quantification in agda

Tags: agda

I could spot the problem and added universe quantification.

But if anyone can spell what is really going on, that would be interesting.

```
module Level0Equality (A : Set) where
  data _Tauto'_ :  A → A → Set where
    refl2 : (a : A) → a Tauto' a

  -- universe quantified
  data _Tauto_ {l} {A : Set l} :  A → A → Set l where
    refl2 : (a : A) → a Tauto a

  -- PEq x =  the type of proof that y ≡ x 
  data PEq  {A : Set} ( x : A ) : Set  where
    it : (y : A ) -> (y Tauto x ) -> PEq x

  -- does not work because of lack of universe quantification in Tauto'
  -- A !=< A of type Set
  -- (because one has deBruijn index 2 and the other 3)
  -- when checking that the expression y has type A
  data PEq'  {A : Set} ( x : A ) : Set  where
    it : (y : A ) -> (y Tauto' x ) -> PEq' x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your definition of `PEq'` tells us that it works for any `A` from `Set`. However, `_Tauto'_` only works for the one particular `A` that the user provides as the module parameter to `Level0Equality`.

Let me demonstrate it with an example:

```
open Level0Equality Bool

_Tauto'_ : Bool → Bool → Set
PEq' : {A : Set} → A → Set
```

Say we choose `A = String`, then we have:

```
PEq' {A = String} : String → Set
```

This will obviously cause problems in the `PEq'.it` constructor. The type of both `x` and `y` is now `String`, but the equality `_Tauto'_` only works for `Bool`s!

---

The fix is rather simple: use the `A` from the module telescope.

```
data PEq' ( x : A ) : Set  where
  it : (y : A ) -> (y Tauto' x ) -> PEq' x
```